# Best algebraic approximations

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, approximation, transcendental-numbers

Continued fractions are a well-known method for producing rational approximations to given real numbers, which can be shown to be optimal with an appropriate optimality measure.

Does there exist a similar method for producing a best *algebraic* approximation to a given real (or complex) number? As with rational numbers, the algebraic numbers are dense in the complexes, so it is important to bound the "complexity" of the approximation if one hopes to get a definite answer, but since the approximation method will dictate this choice to some degree, I will be vague about the actual complexity measure.

Answer (score 6):

You might be interested in [integer relation algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_relation_algorithm). These take high-precision approximations to some real numbers of interest and try to find *small* integer coefficients (with a suitable definition of *small*) such that the given numbers combine to something that might be zero within the uncertainty caused by the limited working precision.

To find a polynomial with integer coefficients that has among its roots a given, supposedly algebraic, number $x$ of degree less than or equal to $n$, one would feed high-precision approximations of $(1, x, x^2, \ldots, x^n)$ to such an algorithm.

[Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/) uses an LLL-based integer relation algorithm as part of its [`lindep`](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/dochtml/html/Vectors__matrices__linear_algebra_and_sets.html#lindep) and [`algdep`](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/dochtml/html/Vectors__matrices__linear_algebra_and_sets.html#algdep) functions.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to turn such an algorithm into a sequence of convergents for a real number. The formulation of the problem sounds like it is important that the linear combination sums to exactly zero, rather than simply returning the smallest linear combination that is discovered in the range. I suppose if you kept the precision low you might stave off a declaration that there are no solutions, but this seems like a misuse of the algorithm.

Comment: Sequence of convergents, hmmm... maybe you are interested in [Greg Martin: The Unreasonable Effectualness of Continued Function Expansions, arXiv 2002](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0206166v1), theorem 4. I do not know whether that is practical however.